# How to pass arguments to an AutoIt script from Java code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I wrote a Selenium script to download an Excel sheet, open, edit and upload it back. I use AutoIt for the file upload.

I have different files to upload for each run, so I can't hard code the file path, hence I want to pass it (to the AutoIt script) as an argument. The AutoIt script:

```
ControlFocus("File Upload", "", "Edit1")
Sleep(1000)
ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", "C:\Users\nilasing\Downloads\somefilename")
Sleep(1000)
ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Button1")
```

`"C:\Users\nilasing\Downloads\somefilename"` is the hard coded path.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in command line parameters to the script, then read them using the `$CmdLine` array.

```
ControlFocus("File Upload", "", "Edit1")
Sleep(1000)
ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
Sleep(1000)
ControlClick("File Upload", "" , "Button1")
```

See https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm#CommandLine for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the same method:
In my AutoIT au3 file -

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
```

Then call the AutoIT executable from Selenium WebDriver with -

```
String fileName = "C:\\Calendar.xls";   //  passed as a command line parameter to AutoIT executable below
String autoITExecutable = ".\\AutoITFileUploadWithParam.exe " + fileName;
.......
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoITExecutable);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Ran AutoIT script to upload : " + fileName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    test.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Failed to run AutoIT script : " + e.getMessage());
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Send']")).click();
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Email sent");
```

Note the space between the AutoIT executable and the parameter in String autoITExecutable

Comment: Parameterizing file path is one thing, but how can I make same script work for cross browser i.e. the upload window's  title is "Open" for Chrome or Edge instead of "File upload" in case of firefox..?